# How to convert a selection to a channel in gimp?

Tags: gimp

Googling for that, I get a tremendous amount of hits to the opposite direction (converting a channel to a selection).

[image]

However, this is exactly not what I want. I want to convert the current selection to a channel (which can be R, G, B, A or any free-edited below).

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done via the Select > Save to Channel menu entry, see https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-selection-to-channel.html